# R Shiny: Mouse Hover Text for Datatable Rows

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, hover, dt

Is there a way to display mouseover text upon hovering over a row (record) in datatable display? After going through some similar questions on StackOverflow, I found 2 example codes, one that displays hover text for a column cell and one that highlights the entire row on mouse hover.

**Example code for displaying column cell hover text:**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    DT::dataTableOutput("table2")

  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$table2<-DT::renderDataTable({
      responseDataFilter2_home<-iris[,c(4,3,1)]
      displayableData<-DT::datatable(responseDataFilter2_home,options = list(rowCallback = JS(
        "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
        "var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2]",
        "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
        "}")
      ))#, stringAsFactors = FALSe, row.names = NULL)
    },server = TRUE, selection = 'single', escape=FALSE,options=list(paging=FALSE,searching = FALSE,ordering=FALSE,scrollY = 400,scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                          columnDefs = list(list(width = '800%', targets = c(1)))),rownames=FALSE,colnames="Name")

    }
 )
```

[image]

I also found another code that highlights the entire row upon hover:

**Example code for highlight row on mouse hover**

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover {background-color: pink !important;}')),
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'))
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(    
    datatable(mtcars)
  ) 
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]

In my case, I wish to display text upon mouse hover over a row of the datatable. How shall I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {

        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
            DT::datatable(iris, rownames = FALSE,
                          options = list(rowCallback = JS(
            "function(row, data) {",
            "var full_text = 'This rows values are :' + data[0] + ',' + data[1] + '...'",
            "$('td', row).attr('title', full_text);",
            "}")))
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155336/dt-cell-hover-showing-cell-based-sample-sizes-from-hidden-column. This is a questions looking for an extension of your awesome answer here..

Comment: Works! Thanks :)